# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=101)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

So, I wanted to add pagination into my app. It works the first time when I want to show the user, but then it didn't work went I want to show my posts. They pointed out that the problem is in my controller, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    # binding.pry
    # debugger
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Tute 6!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    #@users = User.all
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

```
db/seeds.rb
User.create!(name: "Example User",
  email: "example@railstutorial.org",
  password:
  "foobar",
  password_confirmation: "foobar")
99.times do |n|
  name = Faker::Name.name
  email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
  password = "password"
  User.create!(name: name,
    email: email,
    password: password,
    password_confirmation: password)
end

users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
  users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
end
```

If you can help me, thank you.

Comment: Embarrasing question, but how do I remove this question I already make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the error happen because I'm still in my homepage when I did rails db:migrate:reset, and rails db:seed. When I did this, it effectively also erase the data I add when sign in. That's why they are confused. After I'm going back to the homepage and sign in again, the users and my account work. So yeah, it's embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

I you create 99 users, you should not find user 101. Don’t know if you use a gem or have written your pagination logic yourself, but I suspect the problem lies there that is counts one too many of your records. If you just implemented the pagination system, I would scrap it and move to pagy (gen pagy) very simple and solves your problem quicker than figuring out where this exstra user count comes from

Best of luck!